# How to send HTTP body plain text for GET method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsurlrequest

I had a problem, I use the [iGDB REST API](https://api-docs.igdb.com/#fields) which need to send some **plain text** for some endpoints with **GET** method.

There is no problem with **PostMan** (by selecting "Body" > "raw" & paste my query), but when I try with Objective-C, an error appear telling me "*GET method must not have a body*"...

[image: PostMan example]

Here is the **code** used in my app:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"MY_URL"]];
[request addValue:@"text/plain" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setHTTPBody:[@"sort popularity desc;" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

**EDIT 02/10/2019**

Trying to add each filters in headers not working...

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"MY_URL"]];
[request setValue:[[@"id,name,first_release_date,release_dates,cover,platforms" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0] forHTTPHeaderField:@"fields"];
[request setValue:[[@"popularity desc" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0] forHTTPHeaderField:@"sort"];
[request setValue:[[@"5" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0] forHTTPHeaderField:@"limit"];
[request setValue:[[@"0" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0] forHTTPHeaderField:@"offset"];
```

Thanks in advance for any replies !

Comment: Would love to know how you fixed this since I'm working with the same issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's no longer possible to send a GET request with a body, you'll have to send the data via the query string of the URL, either by building the string manually or with the help of `NS(Mutable)URLComponents`.

---

As per the [iOS 13 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_ipados_release_notes/ios_13_release_notes#3319752.), GET requests are no longer allowed to have a body:

> All URLSessionTask instances with a GET HTTP method that contain a body now produce the error NSURLErrorDataLengthExceedsMaximum. (46025234)

This makes `URLSession` more conformant with the [HTTP/1.1 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.3):

> A message-body MUST NOT be included in
> a request if the specification of the request method (section 5.1.1)
> does not allow sending an entity-body in requests.

Answer (score 0):

If I get true your question, you can set parameters to your request header when you get you can set like below.

```
  [request addValue:@"valueForKey1" forHTTPHeaderField:@"key1"];

  [request addValue:@"valueForKey2" forHTTPHeaderField:@"key2"];
```

If you send a data format so,

```
NSString *stringValueOfParameters =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"userName:blabla"];
NSData *convertedDat=[stringValueOfParameters dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *headerValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@",[convertedDat base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]];

[request setValue:headerValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"headerKey"];
```

// Edit

You must try kinda like that, directly write a `Dictionary` or like below write your `JSON` parameters as `NSString` then convert it to `Data`.

```
NSDictionary *dictParams = @{ @"fields" : @[@"id",@"name",@"first_release_date",@"release_dates",@"cover",@"platforms"], @"sort" : @"popularity desc", @"limit": @5, @"offset":@0 };
```

// this is taken from an example

```
NSString *jsonString = @"{\"ID\":{\"Content\":268,\"type\":\"text\"},\"ContractTemplateID\":{\"Content\":65,\"type\":\"text\"}}";
NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Then try it to set header.

Comment: Thanks for your response ! But it seems not work ... My full payload is "fields id,name,first_release_date,release_dates,cover,platforms; sort popularity desc; limit 10; offset 0;" but when I try to add a parameter for each, the response data is not affected...

Comment: hey @iStornZ can you look at my updated answer, try the code all parameters in a string then convert it to stringencoding data format.

Comment: Thanks @elia, but it's not working too, please check my edited post to see if I do it correctly :).